# How can an element height be auto increased?

Tags: html, css, height

I have a popup element. Content is not fixed so it can increase or decrease. My question is how can I implement that so the element height would increase according to content. I have used min-height but its getting scroll on content increase. I don't want scroll.

Comment: you can use `min-height: inherit;` and `height:auto`

Comment: Unless you set height of an element, its height will vary based on the content. I think your popup have set fixed height some where, may be for some parent element. if you share the code, it will be easy to find it out. share min code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `height: auto` and make sure none of your parent or child elements have any absolute widths or heights set.

You can do a `overflow: hidden` to disable the scrollbar altogether.

Answer (score -1):

Try `min-height: 100%;` and `height:auto`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `height:auto` your content and set `min-height:100%`